# MacBook Pro - Can't get to recovery mode

Tags: macbook-pro, recovery

I was given a 2nd hand MacBook Pro. When I tried to boot with Command+R to get into the recovery mode I get this lock screen.

[image]

I don't know the password - is there any way to reset it?

Comment: You need to talk to the previous owner so it can be unlocked properly.

Comment: The easiest way is to first get proof of ownership, then bring it to an apple store to remove that screen.

Answer (score 1):

That's the screen for a firmware password. An Apple Store or Apple Authorized Service Provider can remove it for you assuming the machine is newer than 2011 and you can prove ownership.

Other than that, there are a few low probability solutions you can try yourself:

- Internet Recovery Mode by holding Option-Command-R or Shift-Option-Command-R at startup.
- Boot from an external hard drive.
- Create a bootable macOS USB flash drive ([instructions here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201372)).

Comment: For Apple to remove the Firmware Password, you _will_ need to provide proof of ownership.

Answer (score -1):

If the machine is attached to an iCloud account, you can wipe the machine.

I think you will need to go to an Apple store with the original owner or proof of ownership.

Don’t whine about it. This is a feature that keeps stolen Mac’s from becoming a thing. With Catalina, the original user will even be able to track the location of a stolen device, even if it’s off and the battery has been removed.